# Force HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: redirect, ssl, iis, sharepoint, https

I have a site on SharePoint and I have implemented HTTPS successfully.

However, if user goes to the URL and remove 's' from 'https' then site becomes accessible without SSL.

I want a way to force redirect the user to HTTPS in all cases. How can I achieve this using IIS or SharePoint Central Administration?

Comment: Is this apache server? do you use .htaccess?

Comment: It is windows server 2012 IIS

Answer (score 0):

The IIS rewrite module has a template configuration for this very purpose. YOu can download it [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and theres a sample [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153050.aspx?URL%20Rewrite%20for%20SSL%20redirection) if you are stuck. Its a very powerful and much underused extension in IIS IMO.